# How to create vertex and edge RDDs for usage in GraphX from vertex and edge tables in HCatalog

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have a table named vertex_table stored in HCatalog that includes a vertex_id type Long, vertex_name type String, vertex_label type String.
I have also stored in HCatalog a table named edge_table that includes the following fields: ida type Long, idb type Long and edge_label type String.

From the scala REPL shell in Spark I am able to query these tables successfully using a hiveContext. For example:

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
hiveContext.hql("SELECT vertex_id, vertex_name, vertex_label FROM vertex_table")
```

I want to create an Apache Spark GraphX graph from these 2 tables.

I am at rookie level at Spark, GraphX and scala. I therefore would be helped with a scala script creating the vertex and edge RDDs from my HCatalog tables available in a hyveContext in Spark. An example to create the vertex RDD from the HCatalog vertex_table will be sufficient.

My own experiments result in the following error:

```
scala> val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, String, String)] = hiveContext.sql("SELECT vertex_id, vertex_name, vertex_label FROM vertex_table")

<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, String, String)]
     val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, String, String)] = hiveContext.sql("SELECT vertex_id, vertex_name, vertex_label FROM vertex_table")
                                                                                                                     ^
```